# Using a SMIL video stream in MediaElement.js

Tags: javascript, html, video, mediaelement.js, smil

Can anyone explain how to play video streams wrapped in a SMIL file using MediaElement.js?

JW Player supports this, but I'm curious if this is possible using MediaElement.js.

Comment: Hi Have you find the answer

Comment: Have you found anything? :)